# Stripe application fees not visible. Combined with Stripe fees into one value

Tags: stripe-payments, xero-api

I am developing a SaaS using Stripe Connect with standard accounts using direct charges and charging an application fee for each payment.

It seems there is no way for the connected account to see how much they have been charged in total application fees as these fees are combined with the Stripe fees on all reports and csv exports.

The connected accounts link the Stripe account to Xero and from what I have been told the application fees are not visible.

**There are a couple of ways to see the application fees but these are not that practical.**

You can see them split if you view the payment in the console and hover over the "i" for the fee, but this is a manual process and you can only see one at a time.  No use for 1000's of fees.

You can also use following APIs:
From the connected account: https://stripe.com/docs/api/balance_transactions/list
From the platform account: https://stripe.com/docs/api/application_fees/list

I am using these to generate a monthly report of application fees but this is outside of the connected account software (Xero) and I am not sure how this would be combined and reconciled.

Apologies if the above is not clear as I am more a developer than an accountant.

If this question is not specific enough or outside the guidelines let me know and I will rewrite or remove.

**UPDATE:**

It appears this is not possible at all in Stripe.
The solution I will attempt is to add calculate the Stripe fee using the total charge and subtract this from the total fee to calculate the Application fee.  I have no idea if this will work in Xero (it appears not so far) but this is the solution Stripe offer for reports.  The suggest exporting as csv and adding this formula to calculate the fee.
Not very helpful.

Comment: If your question is how Standard connected accounts see how much they have been charged in total application fees - this is really more of a question that should be directed to Stripe Support (https://support.stripe.com/contact) who can share what possible options/reports are available (if any) on the Dashboard.  

If your question is how Standard connected accounts see how much they have been charged in total application fees on Xero, then this question should be directed to Xero Support instead.

Comment: @alex thanks for the response.  The question is both of those. I have already tried Stripe support and they say this is not possible however my experience with Stripe support in the past there may be a way that they are unaware of.  I will try with Xero support for the 2nd part once I get an account.

Comment: Xero support was no help they just pointed me at Stripe.

Comment: It makes absolutely no sense why Stripe wouldn't make this more intuitive on the dashboard....